# How to disconnect discord.py (self)bot?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I am creating a Discord self-bot that will run for multiple users, thus needing to disconnect each time one user is finished with the bot. **Is there any way I can programmatically disconnect the selfbot from the user's account without stopping the entire application?**

Thanks in advance,

ICT :)

Answer (score 12):

[`Client.logout()`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.logout) or [`Client.close()`](http://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.close)

Comment: I must've been looking at something completely different. Thanks :)